# How to implement/calculate this function in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, xcode, math

CUMIPMT(Rate,NumberOfPayments,PresentValue,StartPeriod,EndPeriod,Type).?
plz tell me a step by step guide how this formula works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that computes a basic compound interest formula. You can read more about compound interest all over the web, in particular at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound

The formula they give isn't the exact same form as above, but it's the same concept.

Comment: sorry i can't understand the formula from your given link.could you please tell me how to calculate this formula?

Answer (score 1):

That's the MS Excel compound interest formula -

[Reference Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052090381033.aspx)
and here's a 
[Short video of how it's used](http://www.tvlesson.com/video/6421_excel-finance-trick-18-cumipmt-function-for-interest.html)

As to its actual implementation, the wikipedia link is the best guide I've found also.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [`get_cumipmt(..)`](http://www.koders.com/c/fidFF5D25C2282C5FAEE1D0AFE3220DA0A906D6D3D7.aspx?s=CUMIPMT#L271) or [`AnalysisAddIn::getCumipmt(..)`](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid4B9ED60F6C035E346E7365383408FF0F340C282C.aspx?s=cumipmt#L174) @ koders.com

Please note that these are under LGPL and GPL, if you plan to copy it, but they can be good to look at when making an own implementation.