# excel cumipmt formula to coldfusion

Tags: excel, function, coldfusion

I am trying to replicate excel's cumipmt formula (cumulative interest paid on a loan between start period and end period) in coldfusion.

Excel's version takes rate, nper [total number of payment periods], present value, start, end and type [equals 0].

Does anybody have the equation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is just a single equation or formula with which you can find cumulative interest paid between two periods. This is what you have to do

```
a) Find the monthly payment keeping in view whether the payment is made at the end or at the beginning of period [PMT]
b) Find the total interest paid by the end period
1. Find the outstanding principal by the end period [OP_E]
2. Find the total principal paid by the end period [TP_E] = PV - [OP_E]
3. Find the total amount paid by the end period [TA_E] = PMT x end
4. Find the total interest paid by the end period [TI_E] = [TA_E] - [TP_E]
c) Find the total interest paid by the start period minus 1
1. Find the outstanding principal by the start period [OP_S-1]
2. Find the total principal paid by the start period [TP_S-1] = PV - [OP_S-1]
3. Find the total amount paid by the start period [TA_S-1] = PMT x start - 1
4. Find the total interest paid by the start period [TI_S-1] = [TA_S-1] - [TP_S-1]
d) Now find the CUMIPMT = [TI_E] - [TI_S-1]
```

This [CUMIPMT Calculator](http://www.thinkanddone.co.uk/en-gb/excel_cumipmt_calculator.html) uses the above or similar algorithm to calculate the [cumulative interest](http://www.thinkanddone.co.uk/en-gb/excel_cumipmt_calculator.html) paid on a loan

Comment: In another discussion on the same topic [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891659/how-to-implement-calculate-this-function-in-objective-c) someone pointed to an algorithm developed at Sun Microsystems for the CUMIPMT function here at [link](http://www.koders.com/c/fidFF5D25C2282C5FAEE1D0AFE3220DA0A906D6D3D7.aspx?s=CUMIPMT#L271) Yet looking at the specific implementation I see a for loop that iterates through start and end values thus consuming more processing than the algorithm I listed above. There may be other solutions yet I am not aware of a straightforward formula that will do it